# DocInteraction sample code (UIDocumentInteractionController) broken on iOS 4.3 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

The DocInteraction sample code made available by Apple at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html 
(download: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/DocInteraction.zip ) does not work when simulating on 4.3. It works fine on 4.2 though. I've looked through but don't get any errors or any warnings. Not really sure what's going on. Thought I'd ask here. I already reported it. It just loads a white screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing the line number 53 with following code in **DITableViewController.h**

```
@interface DITableViewController : UITableViewController <QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate,
```

It was missing the **QLPreviewControllerDelegate** delegation.