# how to open pdf on other application like ibooks

Tags: objective-c

I use UIDocumentinteractioncontroller to open pdf on other app like ibook.

But it is hard to find the doc about it.

Now I can present the open in part. but when i click on the icon of ibooks. nothing happend.

Do I need to do something in the delegate such as documentInteractionController:willBeginSendingToApplication:???

Comment: Answer is there in the following post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741565/docinteraction-sample-code-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-broken-on-ios-4-3-s

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate in your .h file

i.e.:

```
@interface MyDocumentViewController : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

in your .m file you add the protocol, which enables you to find out, what happens ...

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application{
    NSLog(@"Send to App %@  ...", application);   
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application{
    NSLog(@"Finished sending to app %@  ...", application);   

}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"Bye");   

}
```

of course you have to set the delegate of the UIDocumentInteractionController to this module. I solved it like this:

```
-(BOOL)canOpenDocumentWithURL:(NSURL*)url inView:(UIView*)view {
    BOOL canOpen = NO;
    UIDocumentInteractionController* tmpDocController = [UIDocumentInteractionController 
                                                      interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    if (tmpDocController)
    {
        tmpDocController.delegate = self;
        canOpen = [tmpDocController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                                    inView:self.view animated:NO];                   
        [tmpDocController dismissMenuAnimated:NO];
    }
    return canOpen;
}
```